# SignalA supports all the versions of android application?

Tags: android

I started some R&D with using SignalA for my native android application which is not a mobile web application.  I am facing some problem while running android app with SignalA on version 2.2 device shows following error.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty
at com.zsoft.SignalA.transport.longpolling.ConnectingState$1.onComplete(ConnectingState.java:50)

So i need some clarifications on the following cases

1) is there any restriction in using SignalA in all the versions of android?
2) What are all the things has to be concentrated while using SignalA on Native Android applications?
3) Does SignalA supports LongPolling transport alone?

Please reply soon if it is possible.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty() shows added in API Level 9. So if your library references it, then it won't be compatible with API Level < 9. The good news is that API Level 8 represents Android 2.2/Froyo, which is marginally represented these days (<3%, mainly older/less powerful devices).

Answer (score 0):

1. I'vent noticed this and I have minSDKversion set to 8 in my samples. I'll have to update this to 9.
   So the minimum version ought to be 9 then. :)
2. Remember to include both signala and signala.longpolling libraries in your project.
3. At this moment is only longpolling supported.